# $\mathrm{ad}$-invariant splitting of Lie algebras.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am reading a text on which the following situation appears:

Let $G$ be a a Lie group and $H$ a compact Lie subgroup. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ be their Lie algebras respectively. The text says it is possible to find an $\mathrm{ad}\mathfrak{h}$-invariant splitting $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}\oplus \mathfrak{p}$, that is a splitting such that $[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{p}]\subset \mathfrak{p}$.

As vector spaces I know it is possible to find a splitting, but how can I ensure that this splitting is invariant under the action of $\mathrm{ad}$?

Comment: See under Cartan pairs [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_decomposition), where you get $[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{h}]\subseteq \mathfrak{h}$, $[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{p}]\subseteq \mathfrak{p}$ and $ [\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{p}]\subseteq \mathfrak{h}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are dealing with real or complex Lie Algebras, not on an arbitrary field.

If $H$ is compact, you can define an $\mathrm{Ad}_H$-invariant inner product on $\mathfrak g$. Since $\mathfrak h$ is a $\mathrm{Ad}_H$-invariant subspace, its orthogonal complement (with respect to this inner product) will also be $\mathrm{Ad}_H$-invariant. Taking derivatives gives your result.

Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply to your answer, and thank you very much. The part I precisely struggle with is: why if $H$ is compact, is it possible to define an $Ad_{H}$-invariant inner product?

Comment: That is some kind of unitarization trick, and you can do that essentially because you can integrate on such groups (do you know Whitney's unitarization trick for finite groups? ).  You can check details on Bredon's book 'Compact Transformation Groups'. Sorry for not giving a complete answer right now.

Comment: On the contrary, thank you for replying! I will look for it in Bredon's book. Thank you very much.